# spark streaming instead of java REST API

Tags: rest, apache-spark, redis, jax-rs, spark-streaming

We have an existing application which receives data from a rest endpoint .
Does some filtering and manipulation and stores it to redis ( an in memory  database).
The senders are receivers( here a receiver is a device which receives data from bluetooth beacons and sends the data to the rest endpoint) and the payload is not big, but the frequency is quite high( tens of thousands per second).This sometime chocs the application.

As spark is considered to be a good candidate for stream processing, our plan is to  keep the endpoint same (because changing the endpoint will need to manually change it in all the receivers across all geography)and use spark somehow within the rest app to process and insert the data in an efficient way.

Spark small batch job will be a problem as for that we have to store the data somehow inside the app for that short period, for which we have to implement some Q, increasing complexity.

Can anyone show some insight.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible yet, You need a queue or some kind of buffer for the microbatches, there is nothing like per record processing , might be available in future releases . read  Chapter 20. Stream Processing Fundamentals. You will get a clear idea

Answer (score 0):

This case is quite common, I have some suggestion for you.

Stack suggested:

- Spark Streaming
- Kafka

With above stack:

- Your endpoint is not changed. With the new implementation instead of process data your endpoint will publish data to Kafka topic.
- Spark Streaming will subscribe Kafka topic, filtering and manipulation and stores it to Redis

[image: Sample Spark + Kafka]

Comment: Is there a way it can be done without kafka, as our data size is quite small, we dont want to introduce another component, if its not a must

Comment: You can use HDFS/S3 as datasource instead of Kafka.

Comment: In that case we will need to add one more component, can be it be done without that, like the rest calls will trigger the spark process, or like storm ?